# How to Compare Enum Ignoring Associated Values?

Tags: swift, enums, compare

How to check the case of an enum while ignoring the associated value?

The below is what I used but it gives an error...

```
enum Example {
        case one(value: String)
        case two(otherValue: Int)
}

var test = Example.one(value: "A String")

if test == Example.one {   // Gives Error 
// Do Something
}
```

*Duplicate question is overly complex.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the below `if case` statement instead:

```
enum Example {
    case one(value: String)
    case two(otherValue: Int)
}

var test = Example.one(value: "A String")

if case Example.one(value: _) = test {   // Works
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Simpler: `if case .one = test {...}`.